# How can I increase open files limit for all processes?

Tags: rhel, limit, ulimit, resources

I can use ulimit but I think that only affects my shell session.  I want the limit increased for all processes.  This is on Red Hat.

Comment: Which version of Red Hat, by the way? RHEL5?

Answer (score 38):

Justin's answer tells you how to raise the number of open files available *total* to the whole system. But I think you're asking how to raise the per-user limit, globally. The answer to that is to add the following lines to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
*               soft    nofile            2048
*               hard    nofile            2048
```

(Where the * means all users.)

There's some summary documentation in that file itself and in `man limits.conf`. This is implemented via the `pam_limits.so` module which is called for various services configured in `/etc/pam.d/`.

And, I have to admit, I have *no idea* where that 1024 default comes from. And believe me, I looked. I even tried without the pam_limits module configured, and it's still there. It must be hard-coded in somewhere, but I'm not exactly sure where.

Comment: Hmm... I set this properly. Exit SSH and come back in and my soft limit is still set to 1024. Is there something I'm missing to make this "active"? Thanks.

Comment: @mattdm - It is worth mention that on some Linux distributions the mentioned file will be under: /etc/limits.conf

Comment: yeah, I've been looking to know where 1024 is set as the default. is it compiled into the kernel?

Comment: additionally we need add `fs.file-max = 65536` in file /etc/sysctl.conf as suggested by RHEL https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2469 and @minhas23

Comment: Potential negative side effects?

Answer (score 27):

Increase max number of ulimit open file in Linux

1.Step :  open the `sysctl.conf`  and add this line  `fs.file-max = 65536`

```
$ vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

add new line and

```
fs.file-max = 65536
```

save and exit.

2.Step:

```
$ vi /etc/security/limits.conf
```

and add below the mentioned

```
* soft     nproc          65535
* hard     nproc          65535
* soft     nofile         65535
* hard     nofile         65535
```

save and exit check max open file `ulimit`

```
# ulimit -a

....
open files                      (-n) 65535
```

Comment: sysctl -p or  logout->login is required to make changes effective.

Comment: This suggestion to have the per-user limit (i.e., "limits.conf") be the same as the system-wide (kernel, "sysctl") one is a recipe for a single user to lock up the system by using up all available files and leaving nothing to anything else.

Answer (score 17):

According to the article [Linux Increase The Maximum Number Of Open Files / File Descriptors (FD)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/), you can increase the open files limit by adding an entry to `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Append a config directive as follows:

```
fs.file-max = 100000
```

Then save and close the file. Users need to log out and log back in again to changes take effect or they can just type the following command:

```
# sysctl -p
```

You can also verify your settings with the command:

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

Comment: I'm skeptical about needing to log out and in again for this particular setting, which is system-wide. (That goes for pretty much everything in sysctl...)

Comment: True. You only need a new login session for ulimit-style settings (i.e., `pam_limits`). `sysctl` is instant and at the kernel level.

Answer (score 17):

But if you're trying to increase the max number of open files of a **service** like MariaDB or something else (using *systemd*) you have to do directly in file .service

```
/lib/systemd/system/<servicename>.service
```

Will be something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some Daemon
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
LimitNOFILE=49152
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/somedaemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The completely answer is here: [Increasing nproc for processes launched by systemd on CentOS 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/628610/increasing-nproc-for-processes-launched-by-systemd-on-centos-7/678861#678861?newreg=42097fa74e6845edb0587c5fa33d63a4)

Comment: This needs to be upvoted, as the ubiquity of `systemd` along with its ongoing changes are increasing across the Linux ecosystem.

Although, I would suggest to edit the answer to `cp -r /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service /etc/systemd/system/` and make the changes to that file, rather than the system-wide service file that's provided by the package.

Answer (score 6):

SUPLEMENT:

You may find config in different place: `/etc/security/limits.d/*.conf`

I had to modify it. It didn't work without it. Format is the same as for `limits.conf`

Comment: I also had to update this file for the setting to fully take on our CentOS servers.